Data tuple vs attribute vector in data mining
The title basically.
From Data Mining: Concepts and Techniques, page 24 describes data tuples and attribute vectors as the following:

If data objects are stored in a database, they are data tuples.


A set of attribute used to describe a given object is called an attribute vector.

Questions

In all the domains which I have studied till now, I have always come across vector as an ordered sequence and not a set. It feels a bit odd. Can you please explain why a set is named as (attribute) vector.

Except that data tuple term is used in structured relational databases only, and that attribute vector is not ordered, is there any other difference?


